# How does a DataSet know how to parse elements from xml files?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

First, i tell my DataSet how to interpret the xml by means of an xsd file. The xml element of question should be a KeyValuePair, the corrosponding line in my xsd looks like that

```
<xs:element name="MyKeyValuePair" msdata:DataType="System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" type="xs:anyType" />
```

The xsd is loaded to the DataSet as follows:

```
myDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(myXsdString));
```

This works fine as i can check in the debugger that the DataType of the column is the right one (I have some strings, some doubles, some System.Guid etc. and - of course - my KeyValuePair). I then load the xml with

```
myDataSet.ReadXml(new StringReader(myXmlString));
```

The xml looks like that

```
<DataSet>
  <DataTable>
    <MyGuid>8F6FC345-5362-4518-B652-0CC3AD54901E</MyGuid>
    <MyKeyValuePair>[67b7fdd1-2079-4311-a7a3-cd2fb0b31384, myValue]</MyKeyValuePair>
    <MyBool>0</MyBool>
  </DataTable>
</DataSet>
```

All Types are parsed correctly, but obviously the DataSet doesn't know how to parse the generic KeyValuePair. How do I tell the DataGrid how to parse specific Types? My guess is to use somehow TypeConverters, but how exactly? Thanx

Comment: How would you think/like the K-V pair to be encoded in a Database?

Comment: that doesn't matter for the moment. The ToString method from in .NET results in "[key, value]", so i might stitch such a string together in my TSQL, but it would be even be better, if i put only the key into my xml and some additional xml elements that describe a dictionary to map such pairs.
The application is that I map a table to a DataGrid and the foreign keys are displayed as Combobox to chose from. And in this Combobox i want to show a readable description, not the guid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the guess to use TypeConverters was totally wrong. The DataSet parses everything that implements the IXmlSerializable Interface. So instead using the generic KeyValuePair, i implemented my own one, that implements the IXmlSerializable Interface.